# How to change projection and show latitude / longitude in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am new to QGIS and pretty ignorant with the subject, but I want to be able to see the  latitude / longitude of a point (with a mouse click) in Quantum GIS.
I imported a shapefile (roads of finland from here : http://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/node/6567 ), and there is a box a the bottom that show the current coordinate in unknow units to me : 521636,6947168, same the coordinate capture don't show lat/long. The coordinate system seems to be WGS84 - 4326.

Comment: Not the answers but something caught my attention. WGS84 and having coordinates 521636 6947168? It doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/node/6567, I can read :

> The datasets can be downloaded from this website in the current national coordinate system ETRS-TM35FIN.

When you open QGIS, set the projection system to EPSG:3067 (according to [spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3067/)). With Qgis 1.7, you can also apply the project coordinates system from a given layer by right clicking it and choose the right option (something like : Define the coordinates sytem with the current layer coordinates system - *my qgis is in french*)